# UITableViewCell outside of UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I notice that InterfaceBuilder has `UITableViewCell` in its library of objects I can drag onto a view. I wonder if it ever makes sense to use one outside of a `UITableView`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`UITableViewCell`s are meant to be used in `UITableView`s only. Feel free to stick them elsewhere, but you do so at your own risk.

Comment: I want to have a wide, narrow button with a title and a subtitle and a disclosure accessory.

Comment: So stick it in a `UITableView` if you so desire. I would strongly discourage using a `UITableViewCell` outside of a `UITableView`.

Comment: it's an in-your-face, sure-of-yourself declaration without giving any justification whatsoever other than "seriously" (and I know how to spell "no", thank you; that is not even relevant)

Answer (score 21):

I have tried this and yes it does not appear to work. Which is, of course, fair, given the purpose and use of cells.

A reason for wanting to do this, in my case I have the cell used in a table view, selecting a cell then pushes on another view, part of which is an exact repeat of the contents of the cell, shown at the top.

So it would be very convenient to simply place the cell at the top on the new view, and have it populated, without needing any extra code.

What I have done is loaded the cell from its nib, set it up, and then added the contentView of the cell to my new pushed view. This achieves the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I've used the approach in shipping apps, never had a problem.

Comment: The answer above was edited to remove a smiley... that must win some kind of editing award surely? :)

Comment: I came here to see if there were some ideas. I'm thinking about taking a snapshot of the cell's content view and add it to a container. This way I can avoid loading the cell from the nib. :)

Comment: @NunoGonçalves yes that should work well too, capture the cell image and then just display that in an imageview. I don't see any specific advantage though, and there's no benefit to avoiding loading the cell from the nib (it will already be in memory because of the tableview).

Comment: If the next screen can cause the data in the cell to be changed, and it should change in your cell, then loading it from the nib and populating from the model means it can be live too.

Answer (score 1):

Best to substitute the `UITableViewCell` with a `UIView` if you want to use it outside of table view... you can try to fake the disclousure indicator by drawing it yourself, or using an icon

If you want to reuse the code, you can put the login in a custom UIView subclass, which is used both in the cell and also in the regular UI

I would discourage using `UITableViewCell` outside of `UItableView` as tempting it may be... the cell conforms to reuse handling and layout resolutions, so while it may look fine, it is a misuse which can trigger unforeseen problems