# iOS UIButton or Single Row UITableView For Dropdown Like Thing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

For iOS 7 and iOS 8, we're implementing these things that look like drop-downs, but each just launch a modal window.

[image]

What makes more sense, using 3 UIButtons, 3 UITableViews with 1 row, or something else? In the past, there would be more than one of these all lined up, so I would put them in a UITableView and set the accessoryView of the UITableViewCell. Using the cell was nice, but three UITableViews seem like overkill here and a maintenance hassel.

The closest post I found regarding this was one about using an [UITableViewCell outside of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770663/uitableviewcell-outside-of-uitableview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantage to using a UITableView or a UITableViewCell. I think this is clearly a case for three UIButtons. You can set constraints to keep them nice and clean. One cool thing that might be worth investigating is using a unicode character for the downward arrow. That way you could have the tap feedback on the whole "thing" as you called it.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I am leaning towards buttons as well.

Answer (score 3):

What would make the most sense is to follow the iOS design guidelines. Instead of trying to create custom dropdown menus (or worse: showing a drop down menu, but displaying a modal view when the user is expecting a drop down view), that UI could be replaced with 1 `UITableView` that has 3 `UITableViewCells` in it. The text on each cell would be the name of the setting to be changed and selecting the cell would push segue to the next page. This will give the app a uniform iOS UX; allowing users to know exactly how to use your app because it works similarly to other apps on their phone. Check out the Settings app on the simulator to see what I am describing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand how my example in isolation may look strange. :) However, it's part of a bigger space constrained page / scene. The UI layout is not up for negotiation as this point. The UX conversations have already taken place.

Comment: Well the way I would implement a drop down menu then is to make the menu as it shows in your screen shot a `UILabel`. You may have to use a `UIView` behind it to get it to show like you have it. When someone touches the label, you can show a `UITableView` below the label that was previously hidden that contains your down down menu items. When the user selects an item, you hide the table view again and update the label text to reflect what was selected.

Answer (score 0):

When I need to create sort of dropdown menus, I usually take advantages from UITableView, one above all is when you will need to add one or more selections in the dropdown you just need to change the data model.
UITableViewCells are easily customizable that means that you can create almost everything you want.
I think that your design doesn't adapt well to a mobile application, those kind of menu are more web style, with 3 buttons and a [`UIPickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html) you can really improve the user experience and also adapt in a really easy way on the ipad embedding the picker in a `UIPopoverController`.

Answer (score 0):

as i agree with @keithbhunter, but still if you want then may this links will help you.

http://code4app.net/ios/DXPopover/54741ca3e24741c56db03ca0

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kxmenu

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nidropdown

Comment: Impressive controls! I will have to investigate those further. :) It's possible a very large popover may be warranted instead of a full modal page.